# Python how to use split delimiter to remove white-space on csv

Tags: python, regex, csv, beautifulsoup, delimiter

I'm working on a piece of code that converts html tables into a csv file. I'm having trouble figuring out how to remove the white-space between the information I'm printing to terminal using string split. My best result has the terminal printing large gaps between information which makes it hard to navigate. Any information would be greatly appreciated.

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from termcolor import cprint

html = open("recallist.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find_all('div', {'id': 'PrintArea'})
output_rows = []
recals = 'recallist.csv'
cprint('READING TABLES', 'green')
for table_row in table:
    columns = table_row.findAll('td')
    output_row = []
    for column in columns:
        output_row.append(column.text)
    output_rows.append(output_row)
    with open('recallist.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerows(output_rows)
    with open(recals, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.read()
        for item in contents.split("Date,Customer,Phone,Cell Phone,Removal,Notes"):
            for refine in item.split('",,'):
                print(refine)
```

A sample of the CSV listed below:

```
Location,,,Date,Customer,Phone,Cell Phone,Removal,Notes,�,�,�,,04/29/19 | 03:00 PM,[9999] FIRST LAST,999-999-9999***,999-999-9999,,"
",,"
","

$127.92
                 ",,04/29/19 | 03:30 PM,[123456] FIRST LAST,999-999-9999***,999-999-9999,04/13/2020,"
",,"
","

$0.02
                 ",,04/29/19 | 04:00 PM,[123456] FIRST LAST,999-999-9999***,,09/10/2019,"
",,"
","

($212.10)
                 ",,04/29/19 | 04:15 PM,[123456] FIRST LAST,999-999-9999***,,01/09/2020,"
",,"
","

$16.23
                 ",,04/29/19 | 04:30 PM,[123456] FIRST LAST,999-999-9999***,,05/30/2019,"
",,"
","

$0.24
                 ",,04/29/19 | 05:00 PM,[123456] FIRST LAST,999-999-9999***,,07/26/2019,"
",,"
","

($0.30)
                 ",,04/29/19 | 07:00 PM,[123456] FIRST LAST,999-999-9999***,999-999-9999,11/15/2019,"
",,"
","

$0.06
                 ",,04/29/19 | 07:30 PM,[123456] FIRST LAST,999-999-9999***,,12/12/2019,"
",,"
","
```

The format I'm trying to achieve:

```
04/29/19 | 03:00 PM,[9999] FIRST LAST,999-999-9999***,999-999-9999,$127.92
04/29/19 | 03:30 PM,[99999] FIRST LAST,999-999-9999***,999-999-9999,$0.02
ETC.
```

Sample of html in case it is needed:

```
<tbody><tr class="alt">
            <td colspan="5" align="left" style="background-color:668cd9;">Location</td>
            <td colspan="5" align="left" style="background-color:668cd9;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="left" class="GrayBLOCK">
              <td></td>
              <td>Date</td>
              <td>Customer</td>
              <td>Phone</td>
              <td>Cell Phone</td>
              <td>Removal</td>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td> </td>
              <td> </td>
              <td> </td>
            </tr>












               <tr class="alt">
                <td></td>
                <td>04/29/19 | 03:00 PM</td>
                <td><a href="../code/c_newClient.cfm?theID=99999" target="_blank">[9999]</a> FIRST LAST</td>
                <td>999-999-9999***</td>
                <td>999-999-9999</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
    </td>
                <td align="right" class="RedMED">

$127.92
                 </td>
              </tr>











               <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>04/29/19 | 03:30 PM</td>
                <td><a href="../code/c_newClient.cfm?theID=99999" target="_blank">[999999]</a> FIRST LAST</td>
                <td>999-999-9999***</td>
                <td>999-999-9999</td>
                <td>04/13/2020</td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
    </td>
                <td align="right" class="RedMED">

$0.02
                 </td>
              </tr>











               <tr class="alt">
                <td></td>
                <td>04/29/19 | 04:00 PM</td>
                <td><a href="../code/c_newClient.cfm?theID=99999" target="_blank">[999999]</a> FIRST LAST</td>
                <td>999-999-9999***</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>09/10/2019</td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
    </td>
                <td align="right" class="RedMED">

($212.10)
                 </td>
              </tr>











               <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>04/29/19 | 04:15 PM</td>
                <td><a href="../code/c_newClient.cfm?theID=99999" target="_blank">[999999]</a> FIRST LAST</td>
                <td>999-999-9999***</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>01/09/2020</td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
    </td>
                <td align="right" class="RedMED">

$16.23
                 </td>
              </tr>











               <tr class="alt">
                <td></td>
                <td>04/29/19 | 04:30 PM</td>
                <td><a href="../code/c_newClient.cfm?theID=99999" target="_blank">[999999]</a> FIRST LAST</td>
                <td>999-999-9999***</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>05/30/2019</td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
    </td>
                <td align="right" class="RedMED">

$0.24
                 </td>
              </tr>











               <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>04/29/19 | 05:00 PM</td>
                <td><a href="../code/c_newClient.cfm?theID=99999" target="_blank">[999999]</a> FIRST LAST</td>
                <td>999-999-9999***</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>07/26/2019</td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
    </td>
                <td align="right" class="RedMED">

($0.30)
                 </td>
              </tr>











               <tr class="alt">
                <td></td>
                <td>04/29/19 | 07:00 PM</td>
                <td><a href="../code/c_newClient.cfm?theID=99999" target="_blank">[999999]</a> FIRST LAST</td>
                <td>999-999-9999***</td>
                <td>999-999-9999</td>
                <td>11/15/2019</td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
    </td>
                <td align="right" class="RedMED">

$0.06
                 </td>
              </tr>
```

Comment: Try the `strip()` function, which will trim out the whitespaces.

Comment: No luck as of yet, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I'm far away from my laptop. Will test this as soon as I'm near to it and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I found an issue in my original post, here are better versions. The empty `<td>` tags create some extra columns. Version 1 leaves those columns in, version 2 removes them but it's very specific to the format you've given and the slices would have to modified if the format changed.

VERSION 1

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("recallist.html") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), features="html.parser")

rows = soup.find_all('tr')
with open('recallist.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in rows:
        columns = row.find_all('td')
        writer.writerow([column.get_text(strip=True) for column in columns])
```

VERSION 2

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("recallist.html") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), features="html.parser")

rows = soup.find_all('tr')
with open('recallist.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    #alt: 'for row in rows[2:]:' to slice off the two header rows
    for row in rows: 
        columns = row.find_all('td')
        del columns[0]
        del columns[-4:-1]
        writer.writerow([column.get_text(strip=True) for column in columns])
```

If your real HTML actually has multiple tables with a variety of columns, this would need to be adapted. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, version 2 worked perfectly. You really saved me countless headaches.

Comment: Glad it fit what you were looking for! @evolve710